# "Riflettere su" versus "riflettere a"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, prepositions

Non riesco a capire quando devo usare la preposizione "su" e quando invece la preposizione "a" dopo il verbo "riflettere" (nel senso di meditare). Ecco alcuni esempi che ho trovato sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riflettere/):

> - Rifletteva *sulla* sua imbarazzante situazione.
> - Rifletti *a* ciò che ti dico.
> - Non hai certo riflettuto *sulle* gravi conseguenze che potrebbe avere il tuo gesto.

Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Io direi "rifletti su ciò che ti dico", ossia userei "su" anche nel secondo esempio. "Riflettere a" mi sembra strano.

[Alcune](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28riflettere%20a%20quello%20che%29%2C%28riflettere%20su%20quello%20che%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28riflettere%20a%20quello%20che%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28riflettere%20su%20quello%20che%29%3B%2Cc0) [ricerche](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28riflettere%20alle%29%2C%28riflettere%20sulle%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28riflettere%20alle%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28riflettere%20sulle%29%3B%2Cc0) [con ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28riflettere%20a%20ci%C3%B2%20che%29%2C%20%28riflettere%20su%20ci%C3%B2%20che%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28riflettere%20a%20ci%C3%B2%20che%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28riflettere%20su%20ci%C3%B2%20che%29%3B%2Cc0) sembrano mostrare che "riflettere a" è quantomeno una forma antiquata.

In sostanza, credo che si possa usare tranquillamente sempre "riflettere su" senza problemi.

Ok, forse c'è un caso in cui si usa "a", però è un po' diverso:

> "Avete già deciso se vi sposate?" "No, non abbiamo ancora riflettuto **al riguardo**"

ma direi che è l'unica eccezione (correzioni benvenute), e comunque si direbbe più correntemente "non ci abbiamo ancora riflettuto (su/sopra)".

Comment: *al riguardo* è un po' da prendere come una singola parola, si usa anche in frasi tipo "non ho ancora deciso al riguardo" ma anche *decidere* si usa solo con *su questa cosa*, *decidere a* non ha senso. 

*Riflettere a* non l'ho mai sentito e sono stato esposto a italiani regionali di varie regioni quindi sono abbastanza sicuro nel dire che è meglio evitarlo anche se c'è nel dizionario, perché come straniero la gente penserebbe che stai facendo un errore e basta.

Answer (score 2):

'Rifletti *a* ciò che dico/dici' è una forma idiomatica usabile — e si usa — come tale, negli altri casi usa *su*.

Answer (score 1):

Riflettere indica sia respingere che meditare.

Nel senso di respingere è transitivo, ed il participio è "riflesso"; nella forma attiva ha il complemento oggetto ("L'acqua ha riflesso i raggi del sole"), e nella passiva l'agente ("I raggi del sole sono riflessi dall'acqua"). Si possono usare "a" o "in" o "su" per la direzione: "riflette la luce a destra / in alto / sugli occhi".

Nel senso di meditare è intransitivo, ed il participio è "riflettuto"; solo forma attiva con complemento di argomento che usa la preposizione "su", con la possibilità già detta di espressioni come "a proposito di" o "al riguardo"  per l'argomento della riflessione ("Rifletti su quello / a proposito di / riguardo a ciò che hai visto").

"Riflettere a qualcosa" è probabilmente un uso regionale, come "ascolta a me".

Ovviamente può essere seguito da tutte le preposizioni che costituiscono avverbi: "Ho riflettuto a lungo (lungamente) / per poco (brevemente) / con attenzione (attentamente) su questo argomento".

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Grazie per l'intervento, ma quegli esempi, fra cui “Rifletti a ciò che ti dico”, vengono dal vocabolario Treccani.